# new and delete in wdk

Tags: c++

I am building a code using the native subsystem and I have problem with `operator new` and `delete`.
I want to use WDK `new` and `delete` but I get these errors:

> : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) referenced in function _main

Is there any way to use WDK's own `new` and `delete`?
Is there any library in WDK that I can use for these function in native subsystem?

Comment: I think, DDK expects this exported symbol as C. Can you try using `extern "C"?`

Comment: I don't think there is a "C" name for "operator new".

Answer (score 1):

Who says WDK even has `new` and `delete`?  It's mostly written in C, not C++.  And any parts that are C++ probably handle their own memory management using the native API.

You should define your own global `operator new` and `operator delete` (which are just memory allocation/deallocation, after all -- the compiler takes care of running the constructor and destructor) using memory APIs which are available in the native subsystem.

Comment: thank you for answering my question but the problem is that i don't want to overload new and delete and i want to know that , is there any way to use wdk 's own new and delete

(when i overload them i've got some problem and i mention it in this post : here and i know about the calling convertion but when i use the lib with other c/c++ mixed project everything goes wrong!!!)

because my project is a combination of c and c++ file and when i overload these functions i've some error in some of the projects!! thanks native99

Comment: @native99: What problem do you have when you provide your own `operator new` and `operator delete`?  I don't see where you tried that.

Comment: @native99: And you got an answer there.  Have you tried defining your own `operator new` using the `CRTIMPL` and `THROW0` macros in the signature?